# DAX - A couple of measures depending on each other

Tags: dax, circular-dependency, tax

From POWER BI table containing a simple series of yearly results (profit or loss), I'm trying to calculate yearly taxable income. For that,

- losses from one or several previous years can be deducted from current profit
- if the amount of previous losses exceeds the amount of current profit, that excess can be applied to profit
- however, the excess of profit over losses can not be applied to further losses

Therefore, taxable income in a loss year is always =0, and  always >=0 in a profit year.

The outcome I´m after might be something like this:

[Taxable income calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2KoL.png)

The issue here is that "Previous losses compensation" depends on "Previous losses balance" and viceversa, generating a circular dependency. I've tried with both measures and calculated columns, to no avail.

Any suggestion will be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, I think I came out with some sort of solution here. Data lie in [Tabla5], and I defined

```
Year's result = SUM(Tabla5[RCAT])
```

In the first place, I considered that every time there's a positive result immediately after a loss, there must be a compensation:

```
Last year's loss compensation =VAR _Comp=
SUMX(Tabla5,
    VAR _CurrentResult= [Year's result]
    VAR _LastResult=MAXX(FILTER(ALL(Tabla5),Tabla5[Year]=EARLIER(Tabla5[Year])-1),[Year's result])
    RETURN
        IF(
            AND(_LastResult<0, _CurrentResult>0),
            MIN(_CurrentResult,ABS(_LastResult)),0
        )
)RETURN_Comp
```

Secondly, we need to find out the amount of tax credit available after this first compensation, by means of:

```
Cumm First compensation = CALCULATE([Last year's loss compensation], FILTER(ALL(Tabla5),Tabla5[Year]<=MAX(Tabla5[Year])))
```

and

```
Prior losses = SUMX(FILTER(ALL(Tabla5),Tabla5[Year]<MAX(Tabla5[Year])),IF([Year's result]<0,ABS([Year's result]),0))
```

and

```
Tax credit available = [Prior losses]-[Cumm First compensation]
```

The third step would be comparing this tax credit still available to the amount of profit available for compensation:

```
Profit available for compensation = IF(
AND([Year's result]>0, [Tax credit available]>0),
[Year's result]-[Last year's loss compensation],0
)
```

and

```
Cumm Second Compensation = MIN(SUMX(FILTER(ALL(Tabla5),Tabla5[Year]<=MAX(Tabla5[Year])),IF(AND([Year's result]>0, [Tax credit available]>0),[Profit available for compensation])),[Tax credit available])
```

The difference between years of this last measure will bring the value of the current year´s second compensation:

```
Prior years losses compensation = [Cumm Second Compensation]- MAXX(FILTER(ALL(Tabla5), Tabla5[Year]=MAX(Tabla5[Year])-1),[Cumm Second Compensation])
```

Finally, we just need to sum both compensations and substract that value from current year's profit in order to find taxable income:

```
Total compensation = [Last year's loss compensation]+[Prior years losses compensation]
```

and

```
Taxable income = IF([Year's result]>0, [Year's result]-[Total compensation],0)
```

The outcome would be something like

[Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5Bca.png)

I've been trying to buid a one-measure-only solution, but I came across with some row/filter context issues that made it too complicated to me. Maybe someone could sort this out.